# git diff, getting just the changed characters

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, sed, git-diff

I want to get list of all characters, that were used to change files in directory.

The closest I got to this problem was using:

```
git diff --color-words="[^[:space:]]|([[:alnum:]]|UTF_8_GUARD)+"
--no-index ./original_directory/ ./changed_directory/
```

By using this command, I get lines with highlighted characters, which were changed. Is there any way to sed/grep/awk the output, so that output will be just the colored characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git diff --color | awk '/^\33\[3[12]m/'
```

1. Use `--color` so that colors are passed to Awk
2. Green lines will begin with the escape sequence `\33[32m`
3. Red lines will begin with the escape sequence `\33[31m`

[Example](//github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/7a90407/music/music-sync.sh#L33)

Comment: works beautifully, just saved me a bunch of time, thanks