# Get character level stats for git diff?

Tags: git, git-diff

Is there a way to get the counts of added and removed characters for a commit (range)?

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834175/git-diff-getting-just-the-changed-characters) which relies on colors - is there a more direct way?